# Are (PRIMARY, SECONDARY / PRIMARY, BACKUP) Domain Controller already exist?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

i know that since Windows 2000 was introduced there are no such things anymore like "primary" and "secondary" domain controllers.

But if I run in the CMD on my redundant Domain Controllers (**DC01=Windows Server 2008R2, DC02=Windows Server 2012R2**) the command "**net accounts**" there is something like PRIMARY and BACKUP.

My DC01 has the computer role "Primary" and the DC02 has the computer role "Backup". What does that mean now? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used only for backward compatibility. What you are seeing is which machine holds the Primary Domain Controller Emulator role, or PDC Emulator.